# Writing array to file code does not work (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, file, casting

**UPDATE: If anyone is reading this and having a similar problem, it seems that the problem was where I converted a double to an int. Where I thought for example 54 was stored as 54.000..., it was actually stored as 53.99999... and when changing to int, it became 53. 
A workaround to this problem which I found out is to simply add 0.5 and so the code that was**

```
int output_buffer=O[m][n];
```

**becomes**

```
int output_buffer=O[m][n]+0.5;
```

---

I have a two dimensional array of doubles called "O". Where

```
double O[3][3];
```

I use these two functions right after the other in this exact order;

```
...
displaymatrixO();
writedecrypted();
...
```

Where

```
int displaymatrixO() 
{   cout << "O is:" << "\n";
    for (int n=0;n<3;n++)
    for (int m=0;m<3;m++)
    {
      cout << O[m][n];
      if (m == 2) cout << "\n";
      else cout << " ";
    }

}
```

And

```
int writedecrypted()
{   for (int n=0;n<3;n++)
    for (int m=0;m<3;m++)
    {
        int output_buffer=O[m][n];
        fputc (output_buffer,opFile);
    }
}
```

Where

```
FILE *opFile;
opFile=fopen ("decrypted.txt","wb");
...
```

When the program is run, the first function (displaymatrixO) outputs the matrix O to screen in this fashion:

```
O is:
49 50 51
52 53 54
3 3 3
```

Which is correct, this is what O is supposed to be.

The second function then is supposed to typecast and write the individual values of the matrix to a file where each value takes up the space of 8 bits/ 1 byte. When I use a hex editor and look at the file, this is what the file looks like(in hex):

```
0x31 0x32 0x33 0x33 0x35 0x35 0x03 0x03 0x03
```

In 8-bit signed integer format (i.e. how O is displayed using displaymatrixO), this is what it looks like:

```
49 50 51 51 53 53 3 3 3
```

i.e.

```
49 50 51
51 53 53
3 3 3
```

It seems to copy O[2][0] onto O[0][1] and O[1][1] onto O[2][1]. I have looked at the code again and again and I can't seem to figure out where I am going wrong! Help if you can...

Comment: Can you try initializing 
        int output_buffer=O[m][n];
 with int output_buffer = 0 first? It's the only place I see in your code offhand that might be where memory is getting reused.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! There is nothing wrong with the code you have posted (As [this program](http://ideone.com/6IwdF) demonstrates). The problem must lie in the code you **didn't** post. Please post the shortest possible **complete** program that demonstrates the error you are seeing. (For more info about this debugging technique, see http://sscce.org/).

Comment: And, just for future reference: what Rob described is called "testcase".

Comment: Actually there is another problem with the whole code, it seems to write the same matrix twice, But I'll post the code anyway, in a shortened form (and removing functions not present in shortest form of main). It does not compile(the upload site), as the site doesn't have MATLAB I assume. Anyway, here it is: http://ideone.com/jtkK7

Comment: Here are the input and output files (encrypted and decrypted.txt);
http://ideone.com/xy1mL

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your are storing your data as **double**, and rounding down when you do this cast:

```
int output_buffer=O[m][n];
```

Make your original array declaration **int** and see if the problem goes away.

**EDIT:** Here is some more info on the subject. [www.parashift.com](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/newbie.html#faq-29.17)

Comment: Yeah, actually that is what created a lot of work. I was using int until I realised that int can store at max 256. The calculations I do with the information can and does output more than 256 and as such I need the array to be of doubles.

But since I know the very final output will be <256 ( has to be, I am simply encrypting and decrypting data @8 bits per matrix value), I know it won't get rounded down anywhere.

Comment: If I had "double" data consisting entirely of integers(in the mathematical sense) and were to convert them to type "int" are you saying the data would in any way be affected?

Comment: It seems this is where the root of the problem lay. Where I thought 54 was stored as 54.000..., it was actually stored as 53.999... and when changing to int, it made it 53. Thanks

Comment: sorry, yes. that is exactly what I was trying to say.